# How to add a new data in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

I have countdown made with handlebars which is added to the data attribute of my element but what I wanted is to add the current year. The framework countdown that Im using is the final countdown which accepts this data-countdown format of "2017/06/14" my html is this:

```
<div class="cd" id="cd" data-countdown="{{month}}/{{day}} {{time}}"></div>
```

What I wanted to achieve is to add the year in the first index as

```
data-countdown="2017/{{month}}/{{day}} {{time}}"
```

This is my js script so far:

```
var currentDate = new Date().getFullYear();

$('.cd').each(function(){
  //get each data-attribute
  var a = $(this).data("countdown");
  var b = a.split(" ");
  //add the current year to it
  b.unshift(currentDate);
  c = b[0]+'\/'+b[1]+'\/'+b[2];
  $(this).data("countdown", c); });
```

Comment: if you use `.attr()` your code works, like `$(this).attr("data-countdown", c);`

Comment: non-jquery answer: `this.dataset.countdown = c;` - equivalent of above

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it errors to  Couldn't cast `11/6 08:00:00` to a date object. I also converted the currentDate to string still doesnt work

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesn't work too. I guess I should just use the handlebars to make the user type the current year but that's not helpful to them right?

Comment: so, not even `c = currentDate + '/' + a;` (note, no need to escape `/`)

Comment: @icedogedev When i run your code, i get `data-countdown="2017/{{month}}/{{day}} {{time}}"` so please make a working snippet of the problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `i get data-countdown="2017....` - which version of jQuery? because jQuery.data that I've used doesn't touch the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prepend the current year to the already existing data.

```
$('.cd').each(function(){
  var getDataCountDown = $(this).data("countdown");
  var getYear = new Date().getFullYear(); // or whatever the year you want
  var newData = getYear + "/" + getDataCountDown;
  $(this).data("countdown", newData); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

As Jaromanda X said it won't change DOM, if we need to change DOM also means we can go for

```
$(this).attr("data-countdown", newData);
```

instead of

```
$(this).data("countdown", newData);
```

Comment: That's the right word I was looking for prepend! Gonna try your idea.

Comment: This wont change the DOM

Comment: Hey, guys it's working! Yea the DOM needed to be updated.
So I removed the `data-countdown` data in the element and created a new one just like what you told me. Then appended it using the `attr()`
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine!

But as you are saying you are getting the error for date parsing you can just append the year to existing data attribute value as suggested by @Rajesh like below.

```
$('.cd').each(function(){ 
 $(this).data("countdown", new Date().getFullYear()+ "/" + $(this).data("countdown")); 
 alert($(this).data("countdown"))
});
```

Using `$(this).data("countdown", c)` you will not able to see the change by inspecting it but if you alert it by `$(this).data("countdown")` you can see that its alerting the changed value because `.data` manages the element's data object not the DOM.

So if you want it for future use you can use `$(this).data("countdown", c)` else use `$(this).attr("data-countdown", c);`.

Hope this helps!